# How to populate Select element in ZF 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

How to populate a select element in ZF 2 ? My entity object has correct value. When i bind object with form, form doesn't populate the select element with actual value.

Can't i do with just $oForm->bind($oMyEntityObject);

Note :: I am not talking about Select element's 'value_options' . I have tried to manually call setAttribute() method and set 'value' property. I just want to know is there anything i can do with bind() method ( $oForm->bind() )

Comment: Shameless plug: [Zend\Form\Element\Select and Database Values](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/). Blogged about this a while ago.

Comment: Thanks for your blog post. Is method "bind()" capable of populating form without any extra code? Currently i am using setValue method to set "select element" active value.

Comment: `bind()` calls `setValue()` internally on all fields that are defined by the bind-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind()` will use the form hydrator that is attached to the form to set the value, so it will depend on which type you use. The class methods hydrator would for instance, would call `$oMyEntityObject`'s public methods that match the form element names.

It is therefore important that the select element `foo` has a corresponding class property `foo` and the class has a publicly accessible `$oMyEntityObject->getFoo()`.

Select elements will also have the additional requirement of the *value* needing to be already within the `value_options` (So if `$oMyEntityObject->getFoo() == 1` then your would require `'value_options' => array(1 => 'Foo option 1')` for it to be correctly set using `bind($oMyEntityObject)`).